# Accessing localhost of a docker container from the host

Tags: docker, localhost, port, containers

I am running the cloudera docker quickstart image (on windows) as explained on the [this page](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/docker-is-the-new-quickstart-option-for-apache-hadoop-and-cloudera/).

I run it using:

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 7180:7180 -p 9080:9080 cloudera/quickstart:latest
```

It runs fine, I am able to run cloudera manager and access it using the url `http://192.168.99.100:7180`. So far so good. I also use tomcat with a simple app on `localhost:9080` inside this same container. How do I access it on my host? I tried using `http://192.168.99.100:9080` but it does not work.

Update: I fixed it by using the vm ip i.e. 192.168.99.100 instead of localhost for the server. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Since you mapped the port to the host (via `-p`), you should be able to access using `http://localhost:9080` from the host

Comment: That is what I thought, but doesn't work. I tried to ping localhost on the container, and it pings fine.

Comment: Somehow I missed the `on Windows` part. You should use `http://192.168.99.100:9080`

Comment: yep, that is what I meant by `container-ip:9080`.

Comment: OK. That is not the container ip though. It is the IP address of the Docker Toolbox Virtual Machine (the container lives inside the VM)

Comment: You are right, let me update my post to avoid confusion.

Comment: What does that mean when you say "I tried to ping localhost on the container". Did you actually run the ping command from inside your container ?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Though I resolved the issue, and updated the post.